# media not opening in a new tab

Tags: media, links, tabs

I have links to many media links that are photos on a post in wordpress. I have the settings as "open in a new tab." Unfortunately whenever I click on them it just opens up the photo on the page I am on and it does not open a new tab.

Comment: It may be a setting in your theme (if not WP core) which is stripping the `target` attribute of the `anchor`. Check all the options of your active theme or switch to WP to test the behavior.